Stampatello e corsivo: altri modi di scrivere la lettera "a" in italiano
Buongiorno,
Su Google Play ho trovato delle app che insegnano a scrivere le lettere dell'italiano in stampatello e corsivo.
Eccole qua:

App per imparare il corsivo di L'Escapadou
App per imparare lo stampatello di L'Escapadou
Però, non riesco a capire come si chiama il modo di scrivere che riporta la lettera "a" in modo seguente (pensavo fosse lo stampatello, invece... è un terzo modo, diverso (e non riesco a trovare un app su Google Play che insegni a scrivere in questo modo):

Qualcuno può fare chiarezza per favore (e magari anche indicare l'app appropriata per imparare questo modo di scrivere per bimbi al di sotto dello otto anni)?
Vorrei almeno sapere come si chiama questo modo di scrivere con la lettera "a" scritta come la ho disegnata in italiano.
Grazie.

È semplicemente lo stampatello minuscolo. Sia lo stampatello che il corsivo prevedono sia le lettere maiuscole (A, B, C...) che quelle minuscole (a, b, c...).

Ma nella immagine la forma dello stampatello minuscolo è diverso.

@JoselinJocklingson: A quale immagine ti riferisci?

Quella che ho disegnato (la seconda). Nella prima immagine (seconda app dal basso) la forma della a è diversa da quella disegnata, anche se riferita come stampatello.

@JoselinJocklingson: Quella che hai disegnato è la forma più usuale della “a” minuscola in stampatello, come puoi vedere nelle frasi che ci stiamo scambiando (a meno che il tuo browser non usi un set di carattere insolito) o in quasi qualunque libro o in qualche campionario di caratteri tipografici (come per esempio https://wavian.com/font-list.html). Poi, in font diverse è possibile che usino glifi diversi; vedi per esempio https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A#/media/File:A-small_glyphs.svg .

Strano che non ci sia una app allora che insegna ai bambini a disegnarli. Sarebbe anche utile per coloro che imparano a scrivere i caratteri del pinyin in cinese.

Interessante il tuo link. Ma la forma di almeno due delle a minuscole in stampatello è chiaramwnte diversa. La stessa cosa potrebbe succedere a parere mio anche per le altre lettere. È così? Grazie.

Succede che alcune lettere abbiano più di una forma possibile, tipograficamente: è la stessa identica lettera, e le differenze sono puramente estetiche, dipendono dal singolo font o famiglia di font. Un esempio lampante è dato dalle due forme principali che può assumere la “g” minuscola in stampatello: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G#/media/File:LowercaseG.svg Ma tutto questo non riguarda specificamente la lingua italiana, bensì tutte le lingue che usano l'alfabeto latino, e quindi ormai siamo completamente fuori tema.
